# Using pdflatex or something similar in R 3.0.1

Tags: r, sweave, pdflatex

I would like to compile a pdf document using Sweave() and pdflatex using R 3.0.1

The sweave() command works, however, pdflatex from the package 'utils' or 'tools' cannot be installed because it is not available for R version 3.0.1).

Is there any other way to compile a pdf from R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `texi2pdf` from the `tools` package

```
require(tools)
tex_code <-
"\\documentclass{article}
\\begin{document}
Hello \\LaTeX
\\end{document}"

cat(tex_code, file = "/tmp/code.tex")

texi2pdf("/tmp/code.tex", clean = TRUE)
```

Just in case you have trouble, there's a `texi2dvi` argument inside this function to choose your backend in my machine the default is `/usr/bin/texi2dvi` but we can change it like this

```
texi2pdf("/tmp/code.tex", texi2dvi = "/usr/bin/texi2pdf", clean  = TRUE)
```

Change it accoring to your settings. I don't have Mac OS but I'm sure that you'll find something similar in `/usr/texbin`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `system`:

```
system(paste("pdflatex",filetopdf))
```

where `filetopdf` is the name of your .tex file.

You can also look at `knit2pdf` from the **knitr** package.

Comment: > system(paste("pdflatex",'test.tex'))
/bin/sh: pdflatex: command not found

Comment: @user1723765 can I assume you latex installed on your system?

Comment: I'm not a mac user, but it sounds like tex isn't on your path. Take a look at `echo $PATH` from terminal. I will be of no help if it's not there, though.

Comment: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin